# Check for a string repeated twice, if word is repeated twice return true if not, False

Tags: python, string

I am using Python and am a beginner.  I want my program to check if a word inputted by the user is repeated or not, I know I have to use a for loop to check if the word is repeated or not... using 'in'

```
word = input("Enter a word:")

def repeatedWord(word):
   for "input by user:" in word 
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

I know this doesn't work, but what would work in order for me to know if the user repeated the word or not using a for loop in strings?

It should return `True` if the word consists of some word repeated twice and `False` otherwise.

Examples:

```
doubleWord("cat") -> False
doubleWord("catcat") -> True
doubleWord("contour"*2) -> True
doubleWord("acatcat") -> False
doubleWord("catcatcat") -> False
doubleWord("catcatcatcat") -> True
```

Comment: have you ever used regex? or do you want to do this "the python way"?

Comment: If you want a helpful answer for a question like this, you need to show some minimal effort: what have you tried?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please try something first and if you come across a specific problem with your code - which you can't already find an answer to on the internet - we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Ropython4 What exactly do you mean by "word repeated twice"? Something like "TomTom"? Does case matter?

Comment: @brianpck Yeah like TomTom and no case does not matter, just the repetition of the word

Comment: Tom is repeated once in TomTom.

Comment: @stark yes sorry, typo. I meant if it is repeated at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rephrase the question, it might be easier to understand how to go about this: **Is the first half of the word equal to the second half of the word?**

We can use Python slicing syntax to divide the word in half:

- `word[:n]`: first n characters of `word`
- `word[n:]`: all the other characters

To get the halfway mark, we divide the length of the word `len(word)` by 2: we will floor divide so that it is an integer.

The following function will do the trick:

```
def repeated_word(word):
    n = len(word) // 2
    return word[:n] == word[n:]
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. How would this return a boolean expression, meaning after the user has entered 'catcat' it'll return True or if they input 'catdog' it'll return False?

Comment: `==` is a boolean operator. `1 == 1` is `True`